# How can I fix the data in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I asked a second question because my last one was getting out of the subject with comments. So I'm trying to make roblox saving the stats of a player but it puts always the basic stats. Even if the player already played.
Here's my code :

```
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local ds = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Data")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local defaultData = {
        coins = 0,
        gems = 0,
        xp = 0,
        level = 1,
        maxstamina = 100,
        maxmagic = 100,
    }
    local loadedData = defaultData
    local success, result = pcall(function()
         return ds:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    end)
    if success then
        if result then
            -- if we've successfully loaded the data, parse the stored json data
            print(string.format("An old player named %s has returned with data : %s!", player.Name, tostring(result)))
            -- player data should look like this :
            -- {"coins":0,"xp":0,"gems":0,"level":1,"maxstamina":100,"maxmagic":100}
            local parseSuccess, parseResult = pcall(function()
                return HttpService:JSONDecode(result)
            end)
            if parseSuccess then
                loadedData = parseResult
            else
                warn(string.format("Failed to parse %s with error : %s", tostring(result), tostring(parseResult))) 
            end
        else
            -- we have a new player
            print(string.format("New player named %s has joined!", player.Name))
        end
    else
        warn(string.format("Something went wrong fetching %s's data : %s", player.Name, tostring(result)))
        -- TO DO: FIGURE OUT HOW YOU WANT TO HANDLE THIS ERROR.
        -- IF YOU DO NOTHING, THE PLAYER'S DATA WILL BE THE DEFAULT DATA USED FOR
        -- NEW PLAYERS
    end

    -- create the leaderstats and hidden values, load the data from the loadedData table
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Model", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local hidden = Instance.new("Model", player)
    hidden.Name = "hidden"

    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = loadedData.coins

    local gems = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    gems.Name = "Gems"
    gems.Value = loadedData.gems

    local level = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    level.Name = "Level"
    level.Value = loadedData.level

    local xp = Instance.new("IntValue", hidden)
    xp.Name = "XP"
    xp.Value = loadedData.xp

    local maxstamina = Instance.new("IntValue", hidden)
    maxstamina.Name = "MaxStamina"
    maxstamina.Value = loadedData.maxstamina

    local maxmagic = Instance.new("IntValue", hidden)
    maxmagic.Name = "MaxMagic"
    maxmagic.Value = loadedData.maxmagic

    local stamina = Instance.new("IntValue", hidden)
    stamina.Name = "Stamina"
    stamina.Value = loadedData.maxstamina

    local magic = Instance.new("IntValue", hidden)
    magic.Name = "Magic"
    magic.Value = loadedData.maxmagic
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local stats = player.leaderstats
    local hidden = player.hidden

    local data = {
        coins = stats.Coins.Value,
        gems = stats.Gems.Value,
        xp = hidden.XP.Value,
        level = stats.Level.Value,
        maxstamina = hidden.MaxStamina.Value,
        maxmagic = hidden.MaxMagic.Value,
    }

    -- wrap the request in a try-catch block to ensure that failures don't throw errors
    local success, result = pcall(function()
        -- save all the data as a JSON string
        ds:setAsync(player.UserId, HttpService:JSONEncode(data))
    end)
    if not success then
        warn(string.format("Failed to save %s's data with error : %s", player.Name, tostring(result)))
        -- TO DO: FIGURE OUT HOW YOU WANT TO HANDLE THIS ERROR.
        -- IF YOU DO NOTHING, THE PLAYER WILL LOSE THIS SESSION'S DATA
    end 
end)
```

More info :

- The game is public but not finished here's the link if you wan't to test it : https://web.roblox.com/games/4867142155/Medieval-Fighting-Simulator-Beta?refPageId=b25ecb6b-40c9-4c28-a4bb-2e4e0a6c6d61
- The Studio API Service is enabled
- There's no error code

How can you help me?

Comment: Can you please post the expected outcome of the data and the current outcome of the data?

Comment: The first depends but the second is this : 

`{"coins":0,"xp":0,"gems":0,"level":1,"maxstamina":100,"maxmagic":100}`

Comment: fwiw, I tried this and all six values load and save correctly. Either I'm missing what the problem is, or your problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: like when you reconnect to the game if you've added coins you keep it?

because for me it put always the basic data. even if it says an old player is returning

Comment: yes, I tested that: Created empty game, added script above into workspace, added part with Touched handler that increases coins when touched. When I add coins, then break out and come back, the coins still are there as expected.

Comment: pretty weird because for me it don't works

Comment: @Night94 where do u putted your script?

Comment: I put the script right under workspace.

Comment: Here's a crazy idea, try changing your DataStore name to something like "DataTest" or "Data2" just to ensure you've got a clean slate.

Comment: i found out an other way : I use DataStore2 and it works. Thank's for helping me guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my answer :

So we must use DataStore2 and then it shall work!

Here's a good DataStore2 tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBfMfB0BwGA

Here's my final code :

```lua
local DataStore2 = require(1936396537)

local defaultCoins = 0
local defaultGems = 0
local defaultLevel = 1
local defaultXP = 0
local defaultMStamina = 100
local defaultMMagic = 100

DataStore2.Combine("Data","coins","gems","level","xp","mstamina","mmagic")

local xpToLevelUp = function(level)
    return 100 + level * 5
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local coinsDataStore = DataStore2("coins",player)
    local gemsDataStore = DataStore2("gems",player)
    local levelDataStore = DataStore2("level",player)
    local xpDataStore = DataStore2("xp",player)
    local mstaminaDataStore = DataStore2("mstamina",player)
    local mmagicDataStore = DataStore2("mmagic",player)

    local stats = Instance.new("Folder",player)
    stats.Name = "stats"

    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    coins.Name = "Coins"

    local gems = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    gems.Name = "Gems"

    local level = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    level.Name = "Level"

    local xp = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    xp.Name = "XP"

    local mstamina = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    mstamina.Name = "MStamina"

    local stamina = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    stamina.Name = "Stamina"

    local mmagic = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    mmagic.Name = "MMagic"

    local magic = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    magic.Name = "Magic"

    local function coinsUpdate(updatedValue)
        coins.Value = coinsDataStore:Get(updatedValue)
    end
    local function gemsUpdate(updatedValue)
        gems.Value = gemsDataStore:Get(updatedValue)
    end
    local function levelUpdate(updatedValue)
        level.Value = levelDataStore:Get(updatedValue)
    end
    local function xpUpdate(updatedValue)
        if updatedValue >= xpToLevelUp(levelDataStore:Get(defaultLevel)) then
            xpDataStore:Increment(xpToLevelUp(levelDataStore:Get(defaultLevel)) * -1)
            levelDataStore:Increment(1)
        else
            player.stats.XP.Value = updatedValue
        end
    end
    local function mStaminaUpdate(updatedValue)
        mstamina.Value = mstaminaDataStore:Get(updatedValue)
    end
    local function mMagicUpdate(updatedValue)
        mmagic.Value = mmagicDataStore:Get(updatedValue)
    end

    coinsUpdate(defaultCoins)
    gemsUpdate(defaultGems)
    levelUpdate(defaultLevel)
    xpUpdate(defaultXP)
    mStaminaUpdate(defaultMStamina)
    mMagicUpdate(defaultMMagic)

    stamina.Value = mstamina.Value
    magic.Value = mmagic.Value

    coinsDataStore:OnUpdate(coinsUpdate)
    gemsDataStore:OnUpdate(gemsUpdate)
    levelDataStore:OnUpdate(levelUpdate)
    xpDataStore:OnUpdate(xpUpdate)
    mstaminaDataStore:OnUpdate(mStaminaUpdate)
    mmagicDataStore:OnUpdate(mMagicUpdate)
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.Buy.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,cost,item)
    local coinsDataStore = DataStore2("coins",player)

    if player.leaderstats.Coins.Value < cost then
        game.ReplicatedStorage.NotEnoughCoins:FireClient(player)
    else
        coinsDataStore:Increment(cost * -1,defaultCoins)

        local buyedItem = game.ReplicatedStorage.Products:WaitForChild(item)
        local clonedItem = buyedItem:Clone()
        clonedItem.Parent = player.Backpack
    end
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.EarnCoins.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,coins)
    local coinsDataStore = DataStore2("coins",player)

    coinsDataStore:Increment(coins,defaultCoins)
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.EarnGems.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,gems)
    local gemsDataStore = DataStore2("gems",player)

    gemsDataStore:Increment(gems,defaultGems)
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.Enchance.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,cost,item,enchancedItem)
    local gemsDataStore = DataStore2("gems",player)

    if player.leaderstats.Gems.Value < cost then
        game.ReplicatedStorage.NotEnoughGems:FireClient(player)
    else
        gemsDataStore:Increment(cost * -1,defaultGems)

        item:Destroy()
        local clonedItem = enchancedItem:Clone()
        clonedItem.Parent = player.Backpack
    end
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.GainXP.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,amount)
    local xpDataStore = DataStore2("xp",player)

    xpDataStore:Increment(amount,defaultXP)
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.LevelUp.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local mstaminaDataStore = DataStore2("mstamina",player)
    local mmagicDataStore = DataStore2("mmagic",player)

    mstaminaDataStore:Increment(25,defaultMStamina)
    mmagicDataStore:Increment(25,defaultMMagic)
end)
```